# How to delete multiple hdfs directories starting with some word in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

I have persisted object files in spark streaming using `dstream.saveAsObjectFiles("/temObj")` method it shows multiple files in hdfs.

```
temObj-1506338844000
temObj-1506338848000
temObj-1506338852000
temObj-1506338856000
temObj-1506338860000
```

I want to delete all temObj files after reading all. What is the bet way to do it in spark. I tried

```
val hdfs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(new java.net.URI("hdfs://localhost:9000"), hadoopConf)
hdfs.delete(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(Path), true)
```

But it only can delete ane folder at a time

Comment: Is it possible to use wildcards `*` in the path when deleting?

Comment: I tried it but it dosen't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, delete doesn't support globs.

You can use [`globStatus`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#globStatus-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-) and iterate over the files/directories one by one and delete them.

```
val hdfs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)

val deletePaths = hdfs.globStatus(new Path("/tempObj-*") ).map(_.getPath)

deletePaths.foreach{ path => hdfs.delete(path, true) }
```

Alternatively, you can use `sys.process` to execute shell commands

```
import scala.sys.process._

"hdfs dfs -rm -r /tempObj*" !
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works for me but your last line need modification fs to hdfs